# appium-webdriveragent: No WDAs on the device

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I am getting this issue while running the appium on an IOS device.

While automating the IOS Apps I am getting the below issue

[no wdas on the device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRNU7.jpg)

Failed to create a session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65 xcodebuild error message:

Platform. : IOS
Device: iPhone 14 /Any Apple device
Appium Version. : 1.22.0 ( Tried with the latest version also )
Xcode Version: 14.2( tried with latest version also)
My local Device: Mac Book Pro (Mac OS: Ventura 13.2.1)

Desired Capabilities :

{
“platformName”: “iOS”,
“appium:platformVersion”: “16.4”,
“appium:deviceName”: “iPhone 14”,
“appium:bundleId”: “com.apple.Health”,
“appium:udid”: “4A0EEB47-98C9-435B-BB11-98E5596065A5”
}

I have also tried to change the signing certificate but getting the below issue

[appium_webdriveragentrunner_locked_project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHvlo.png)

Even if I click on unlock, it does not unlock the project. Instead, it keeps on popping up the same unlock message.

I tried above steps to run the appium . But it couldnt able to run .

Expected. : To run the appium using ios .

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

You will face this issue on MAC because WDA present inside Appium is not compatible with your XCode 14.2.
When you install Appium, it is equipped with latest WDA at the time of released version for example appium 1.22.3 will come with WebdriverAgent 3.17.0
You can check WDA repo for compatible XCode [WDA link]. After 12.4 they have stopped mentioning XCode compatibility. 
Here are the steps to be followed to replace older WDA to latest WDA

1. For XCode 14.2 Download latest WDA from here https://github.com/appium/WebDriverAgent/releases?page=1
2. Download Source code.(zip) from above link on you mac machine
3. unzip file
4. Copy all the files and folders present inside unzipped folder
5. You have to update all these contents into WebdriverAgent present inside Appium Server folder
6. In Mac, Go to Applications
7. Right click on Appium Server GUI > Contents > Resources > App > node_modules > appium > node_modules > Appium-webdriver agent
8. Paste all the contents you have downloaded inside WebDriverAgent folder
9. Check for WebDriverAgent.XCodeProj
10. Open WebDriverAgent.XCodeProj in XCode
11. If project is not open click on folder icon present on top right corner
12. Click on WebDriverAgent
13. In centre panel > TARGETS Select WebDriverAgentRunner
14. Click on Signing and Capabilities
15. Click on "Team" Drop down to sign in your app
16. You can select existing certificate or new certificate where you have to apple certificate
17. Find WebDriverAgent project on top.
18. select WebDriverAgentRunner from drop down
19. Select targeted device from drop down on which you want to execute test cases
20. Click on "Product" menu
21. Click on "Test"
22. It will install WebDriverAgent on you targeted device
23. Now you can try to launch new session from appium inspector